# Average contribution on bitbucket

Tags: git, statistics, bitbucket

I have projects on bitbucket and I was looking into getting some stats of my contribution. I'm mainly looking for average daily contribution for the last month

How can I get this?

Comment: define "contribution". lines added/removed? raw number of commits? That's stuff that can be dug adding more options (`--stat`, limit period of time, etc) to `git log --author="john doe"` and then processing the output.

Comment: @eftshift0 I want to get commits, I'm familiar with the command you wrote but I can't get the "daily average" from it